# How can I show diffrent images and text like testimonials that scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I hope someone can help me with this I am using the following block to show an image and text as a testimonial, I would like to be able to have 6 testimonials with two showing for x seconds before displaying the next 2 and for this to continue a a continuous loop. the following code shows two testimonials side by side on the page.

```
 <article class="span6 pe-bg-one pad-common">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <article class="span3"> <img src="images/people/01.jpg" title="" alt=""/> </article>
                      <article class="span9">
                        <p>some text here</p>
                        <h5>Noname</h5>
                        <h6 class="testimonial-alt">Something</h6>
                      </article>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                  <article class="span6 pe-bg-two pad-common">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <article class="span3"> <img src="images/people/02.jpg" title="" alt=""/> </article>
                      <article class="span9">
                        <p>some text here</p>
                        <h5>Anonymus</h5>
                        <h6 class="testimonial-alt">Awesome Ltd.</h6>
                      </article>
                    </div>
                  </article>
```

is it possible to achieve this I was hoping some JavaScript or jquery would allow me to create the desired effect but my knowledge in writing scripts is limited

any help appreciated

Ok so after a little tinkering I am now using

```
    var divs = $('div[id^="no-"]').hide(),

    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(600)
              .delay(3000)
              .fadeOut(600, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

I have added a div around each section like this

```
<div id="no-1">   
                            <div class="row-fluid">

                  <article class="span6 pe-bg-one pad-common">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <article class="span3"> <img src="images/people/01.jpg" title="" alt=""/> </article>
                      <article class="span9">
                        <p></p>
                        <h5>Noname</h5>
                        <h6 class="testimonial-alt">Something</h6>
                      </article>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                  <article class="span6 pe-bg-two pad-common">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <article class="span3"> <img src="images/people/02.jpg" title="" alt=""/> </article>
                      <article class="span9">
                        <p></p>
                        <h5>Anonymus</h5>
                        <h6 class="testimonial-alt">Awesome Ltd.</h6>
                      </article>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                </div>
```

However this line is for a coloured background which I would like to stay fixed so only the image and text changes `<article class="span6 pe-bg-two pad-common">`

I am stuck trying to get only the image and text to cycle i.e. this block of code

```
<article class="span3"> <img src="images/people/02.jpg" title="" alt=""/> </article>
                      <article class="span9">
                        <p></p>
                        <h5>Anonymus</h5>
                        <h6 class="testimonial-alt">Awesome Ltd.</h6>
                      </article>
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content is static, add all testimonials with an `id=article1` to `id=article6` and `style="display:none"`

For example

```
<article class="span6 pe-bg-one pad-common" id="article1" style="display:none">..</article>
<article class="span6 pe-bg-two pad-common" id="article2" style="display:none">..</article>
..
<article class="span6 pe-bg-two pad-common" id="article6" style="display:none">..</article>
```

Then add this script that uses [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to run a function every 2 seconds and  display two testimonials

```
<script>
    var totalCount = 6; 
    var currentId = -1;

    function rotate() {
        //hide previous
        if(document.getElementById('article' + currentId) != undefined) {
            document.getElementById('article' + currentId).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('article' + (currentId + 1)).style.display = "none";
        }

        currentId += 2;
        if (currentId >= totalCount) currentId = 1;

        //show current
        document.getElementById('article' + currentId).style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById('article' + (currentId + 1)).style.display = "block";                   
    }

    setInterval(rotate, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set all your testimonials to `display:none`. Then use `setInterval()` to loop and show/hide the testimonials.

This is a jQuery approach using `each()` function:

```
var testimonials = //YOUR TESTIMONIALS SELECTOR
var len = $(testimonials).length;
var count = 2;
var start = -1
var current = start;

setInterval(function(){
    if(current >= len - 1){
        current = start; //restart the loop
    }

    $(testimonials).each(function(index, element){
        if(index > current && index <= current + count){
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

   current += count;

}, 2000);
```